# Spec($\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$), Spec($\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is the set of the zero ideal and the primes, and $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ is the ideal zero, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, but it is true that $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})\times \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\times \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: In general $\operatorname{Spec}(A\times B)$ is the disjoint union of the two spectra.

Comment: Try to think about $(a,0)*(0,b)=(0,0)$ example. Maybe it would help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly:  note that for $\mathfrak{p}$ to be a prime ideal, you need that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain As $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is clearly not a field with the direct product ring structure we find that each component is an ideal of the given ring, so it must be that $0\times\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q\times 0$ are the only non-trivial ideals. Both are manifestly prime as they are both maximal (quotienting gives a field). So

> $$\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q) = \{0\times\Bbb Q, \Bbb Q\times 0\}$$

For $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ the same will hold, noting that $I= J\times K$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ and $J= (n), K= (m)$ so that $\Bbb Z/n\times\Bbb Z/m$ is the quotient, for this to be integral, one of the factors must be $0$, and the other must be a prime ideal of $\Bbb Z$, so you get

> $$\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z) = \{(p)\times\Bbb Z\}\cup\{\Bbb Z\times (p)\}$$

Comment: Thanks, so for $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})$ those are also maximal ideals right?

Comment: @Irene yes, exactly.